# How do I make bangs transparent?

Tags: toon-shading

[image]

I want to show eyebrows as you can see in the picture.

I tried refraction shader, but it didn't work.

I tried to reduce the alpha value in color, but it didn't work.

How can I show eyebrows on the toon shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get something like I imagine you're going for with a setup like this.

[image: Node setup]

There are alot of ways to get a transition from opaque to transparent along the whole bang polygon, just separating out the G value from generated UV coordinates. This is one of the quickest ways that's 100% procedural, you could also manually paint transparency an use that texture or a mix of the two. Then just use a color ramp to control the contrast of the gradient.

[image: color ramp demo]

Comment: I founded diffrent way. Thank you for replying